# Android Kotlin Parcelize android extension giving error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, runtime-error, parcelable

I have used Parcelize property of Android Extension to get Parcelable data class in Kotlin . It greatly reduces boiler plate code . Initially it was in experimental mode but now its stable . 
I have followed tutorial from below link 
[Parcelable Link](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/a-study-of-the-parcelize-feature-from-kotlin-android-extensions-59a5adcd5909)
where I have made changes in gradle to add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'



androidExtensions {
    features = ["parcelize"]
}
```

Initially , it did not give any compiler error , but on running the app , it gives unresolved reference error for viewbinding did with layout from kotlin . 
The import are good , and it works fine if `Parcelize` property is not included .

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity.*
```

What could be the issue ? 
Does it only tells to use Parcelize property of android extension and leave other properties included from android-extension plugin ?